# PC game, probably on Steam, involving mystic martial arts in a medieval Asian time frame

Tags: story-identification, video-games

First off, this is not *Jade Empire*, although I think it was out at the same time, and was probably looking for the budget market for aficionados of the aforementioned. The main character is a muscular Asian man, I believe, probably dressed in red, some sort of martial arts robe.

Levels involved movement with the keyboard, and attacking with the mouse, I think. I do remember that there was an attack button and a counter button. I never quite got the hang of countering, although I'm pretty sure it was necessary to really advance in the game. Most enemies were generic martial artists, monks perhaps, but occasionally you'd fight someone at a higher level, and they'd generally mix magic and throwing fireballs around. At least one level involved being confined to a rooftop against the boss, only able to move left and right. I think that's where I got stuck, as that level really required you to be pretty good at countering.

You got a score, and a grade, at the end of each level, I think based on speed, avoiding getting hit, and some other factors. I want to say the grades showed up as scrolls.

I believe I played this game in the early 2000s. I definitely played it on the PC, but it might have been either Steam or Desura. I'm 90% certain I got it in either a Humble Bundle or Indie Gala.

Comment: If it were Diablo-style, my guess would be Throne of Darkness (2001).

Comment: @Raj: That doesn't look like a match, but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. *[Kung Fu Strike: The Warrior's Rise](https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/kung-fu-strike-the-warriors-rise)* (2012).

> Kung Fu Strike is an old school action beat-'em-up featuring fast-paced combo-based kung fu fighting. Battle through 28 stages of enemies to earn the most money and highest score based on your performance. Then use your money to learn new attacks, upgrade skills and unlock special Chi Powers in Single Player or local Co-Op. Or take on a friend in Versus Mode to determine who is the best fighter of all.

The rooftop fight is about 14 minutes into this video:

The search term that led me to it was *steam game martial artist red robe*. That brought up a list of matching games that I scrolled through until one looked familiar.